# Apple "App Store Server Notifications" Sandbox Server URL Not Working

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, subscription, storekit

Our app working normally on Ipad and when subscribe and cancel subscription it ok, **but no notification sent to our server !**

I have filled the App Information with the our server Sandbox Server URL,

Our link look like this: https://api.example.com/api/apple-api/noti/v2

[We have read related questions]

We followed the documentation below:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/enabling_app_store_server_notifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think WWDC22 feature **Request a Test Notification** may help you.

ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/request_a_test_notification?changes=_2

This feat request Apple to send a Test notification to your link. If you didn't receive, it may be a link error or App Store bug.(To App Store Bug, resave in the App Store Page may help sometimes)

Comment: Thanks that's will be useful, the problem solved, it was on my server side. but us there is no way to request a test before WWDC22, it was hard to find this bug. your answer will be helpful for sure.